# LEFT JOIN only returns one row from right table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following query;

```
"SELECT goals_challenges.*, 
    products_services.id as psid,
    products_services.url,
    products_services.feature_benefit
    FROM goals_challenges 
        LEFT JOIN products_services ON goals_challenges.id = products_services.goal_challenge_id
    WHERE persona_id = :persona_id"
```

Both tables have an 'id' column, hence the 'psid' alias.

However, despite there being two records that match the goal_challenge_id in the products_services table, only the first row is returned as part of the result set.

EDIT: Proper Data

goals_challenges

```
id    persona_id    title            item_category         solution
173   14            Lead Gen         business challenge    advertising
```

products_services

```
id    goal_challenge_id     url                feature_benefit
1     173                   www.testurl.com    good for testing, mobile
2     173                   www.google.com     good for searching, well known
```

PHP code, including query;

```
public function findByPersonaId($persona_id)
{
    try {
        $this->dblayer->beginTransaction();
        $stmt = $this->dblayer->prepare("SELECT goals_challenges.*, products_services.id as psid, products_services.url, products_services.feature_benefit from goals_challenges LEFT JOIN products_services ON goals_challenges.id = products_services.goal_challenge_id WHERE goals_challenges.persona_id = :persona_id");
        $stmt->bindParam(':persona_id', $persona_id);
        $stmt->execute();

        $this->dblayer->commit();

        $result_set = array();

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $result_set[] = $this->mapObject($row); 
        }

        return $result_set;

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->dblayer->rollBack();
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
}

public function mapObject(array $row)
{
    $entry = new GoalChallenge();
    $entry->setId($row['id']);
    $entry->setPersonaId($row['persona_id']);
    $entry->setTitle($row['title']);
    $entry->setItemCategory($row['item_category']);
    $entry->setDescription($row['description']);
    $entry->setSolution($row['solution']);
    $entry->setProductService(new ProductService($row['psid'], $row['id'], $row['url'], explode(',', $row['feature_benefit'])));
    $entry->SetResearchChecklist($row['research_checklist']);
    $entry->setSubtopics($row['subtopics']);
    $entry->setKeywords($row['keywords']);
    $entry->setStatus($row['status']);

    return $entry;
}
```

What I get returned

```
Array
(
    [id] => 173
    [persona_id] => 14
    [title] => Lead Gen
    [item_category] => Business Challenge    
    [solution] => Advertising
    [product_service] => 
    [research_checklist] => 0,0,0,0,0,0
    [psid] => 1
    [url] => www.google.com
    [feature_benefit] => good for testing, mobile
)
```

EDIT: OK so I've worked out the result I am expecting is there, it's just not in the same goalChallenge object as the other - something in the PHP clearly - any ideas?

I get all the data from the goals_challenges table but only the first row (id 1) from the products_services table.

Is there a problem with my query? I have tried adding "GROUP BY goals_challenges.id" but it doesn't change the result.

Comment: Which table does persona_id belong to?

Comment: The goals_challenges table. The products_services table doesn't have a persona_id - I considered that might be the problem but then why would any row be returned from the products_services table?

Comment: Left side table conditions in WHERE clause is no problem when left join. (Right side table conditions are typically placed in the ON clause instead.) I.e you don't need to move it.

Comment: So the query is ok? Why is only one row being returned?

Comment: Looks perfectly fine to me. Why do you expect more result? Add sample table data, current result and expected result.

Comment: "Why is only one row being returned?" maybe there are 2 rows which are matching the `LEFT JOIN products_services ON goals_challenges.id = products_services.goal_challenge_id` but only one row that holds the correct `persona_id`

Comment: Have added sample data

Comment: Maybe the problem is how you iterate over the result set

Comment: Looks fine to me:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71619/2/0

Comment: Look at my comment, i made an example for him.

Comment: Thanks for the sqlfiddle. However - there are two rows. I am looking for result to be returned, but with the two matching products_services results included - is this possible? Maybe that's where I'm going wrong.

Comment: There are two rows of course. Both matching product_services. Each in one row. Dont get your question?

Comment: I'm going to give full sample data - perhaps I am looping incorrectly, bear with me, thanks

Comment: what is the data type of goal_challenge_id in products_services? if its a varchar type there might some extra space in goal_challenge_id data values

Comment: int(11), same for all id's

Comment: get rid if this line return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Comment: how many rows do you get if you remove the where clause ?

Comment: OK so I've worked out the result I am expecting is there, it's just not in the same object as the other - something in the PHP clearly - any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you should try the query without transaction. Transaction are not that useful for SELECT statements.

Comment: tried, no luck. Must be the way I am creating the ProductService object in the loop, need to create an array of objects really

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks fine.
In ON condition , Column :-  "goal_condition_id" has primary key or not.
Check , if both the columns have primary key.

Thanks
Aman

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT gc.*, 
    ps.id as psid,
    ps.url,
    ps.feature_benefit
    FROM product_services ps 
        LEFT JOIN goals_challenges gc ON gc.id = ps.goal_challenge_id
    WHERE ps.persona_id = :persona_id"
```

Since your goal_challenges table has 1 row you are trying to find any proper match with product_services table. But only one row,

> Select means distinguish rows for me under these conditions and
>   restrictions not duplicate rows for me.

Comment: Is there a way to combine the matching 2 results in the products_services table into the one row from the goals_challenges table?

Comment: into the one row from the goals_challenges table? I didn't understand